# label text update from right to left side

Tags: c#, string, winforms, user-interface, label

how it is possible to set label string in my case with several updated values:

```
 label1.Text = (num1 + "." + num2 + "." + num3);
```

Not in the usual way:

```
                        123.8576.87687
                        17.87.1299987
                        9881.0.87
                        765443345600.08776.877667
                        09.8.112
```

but with update from right to left side if I want locate it near to the right  border of the form, and if this numbers is  a sequence of updated values from given string for one label, each time string with different length:

```
           123.8576.87687
            17.87.1299987
                9881.0.87
765443345600.08776.877667
                 09.8.112
```

of some this way:

```
           87687.8576.123
            1299987.87.17
                87.0.9881
877667.08776.765443345600
                 112.8.09
```

to locate it in the corner of the form:

[image]

Comment: Easy if you're using XAML :)  With WinForms, if you're using 5 different labels then just dock them all to the right.

Comment: @ Michael Puckett II Hello, no for one label with updated  different length string

Comment: Just add more labels and call it a day. lol

Answer (score 1):

Try setting AutoSize to **`false`** and set TextAlign  as **`MiddleRight`**

```
label1.AutoSize = false;
label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Comment: Hello, not sure, but seems like it does not works for me, update is same from left to right, and I can see only one part of string

Comment: you need to set the size

Answer (score 0):

You can define `label` `textAlign` property as below:

```
this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, two things that you should make:

Set the TextAlign property like this:

```
this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Then set the AutoSize property to false:

```
this.label1.AutoSize = false;
```

Make sure the size of the label is big enough to fit all numbers and that is it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory that the problem with label text and autosize is that autosize makes the size of the text field exactly as big as necessary for the text to it. Therfore it does not matter where you put contentalignment. The field changes size according to space needed for containing the text. Location is not changed. So, to workaround this you have to manipulate the position of the label.

```
labData.Text = "text"
int labDataRight = lblData.Right;
lblData.Text = "A slightly longer text"; // Autosize will resize the label
lblData.Left = labDataRight - lblData.With;
```

I haven't tested this profoundly, it might be that the label position will drift after many changes.